# Erase some pictures from a Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, image, erase

The code below deletes all pictures from an Excel spreadsheet. It works well but I would like to be able to erase only some selected pictures, can somebody give me an idea about the way to make it.

The code I currently have is:

```
Sub ClearPics(): Rem  Erase All
  Sheets("PICTURES").Select
  Dim WS As Shape
  For Each WS In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    WS.Delete
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What criteria will you use to select them or do you mean literally selected?

Comment: Replace `WS.Delete` with `If MsgBox("Do you wish to delete " & WS.Name & "?", vbYesNo, WS.Name & "?") = vbYes Then WS.Delete`

Comment: The question is that the SpreadSheet I am talking about has usualy about 30 images (Pictures) but also two Bottons that I do not want to erase, I do not know how to differenciate them.  Thanks for your attention

Comment: @JorgeAyllon you can check the `Shape.Type` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msoshapetype

Comment: @GMalc nice find, did not see that question. Yes this should be marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your comment "*the SpreadSheet I am talking about has usualy about 30 images (Pictures) but also two Bottons that I do not want to erase, I do not know how to differenciate* (sic) *them*".

You can check the [`Shape.Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Shape.Type). Also see the [MsoShapeType Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msoshapetype).

If your button is a Form Control (`msoFormControl`) or an ActiveXControl (`msoOLEControlObject`), you could just skip those types, like this.

```
Sub ClearPics()
    Dim shp As Shape

    For Each shp In Worksheets("PICTURES").Shapes
        If shp.Type <> msoFormControl And shp.Type <> msoOLEControlObject Then
            shp.Delete
        End If
    Next shp
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, but you produced the code quickly and it was accurate.